# paypal account implementation in android application

Tags: android, paypal

I want to implement Paypal functions in my own android app like what I can do anything from my web Paypal account I want to do in app.
is there any API of paypal for this purpose which will give me the login details of user and will help the user to perform transactions from mobile app.
I'm not talking about receiving payment from my own Paypal account, I want to do what I can do in my web Paypal account.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah check out the [Paypal Android SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/), where you can accept credit card and PayPal payments in your mobile apps.

Comment: i don't want to accept payments i want to perform manual transactions like what i do in paypal web account. In other words i want to build android version of Paypal :)

Comment: That i believe is impossible. Paypal would not allow such a thing for security reasons.

Comment: I'v already made a web clone android application of paypal but problem is that paypal user interface is same for both computer browsers and for smart devices. Its interface does not look good in smart devices.Any ways thanks for reply :)